# Javascript to run web slider only on laptop/desktop but not for mobile users

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, if-statement, slider

I am trying to add a javascript command to insert a certain set of images if the user is on a laptop/desktop and insert a slider (using Nivoslider) if the user is using a mobile device. Here is just the html code which works before I try to add the screen size check:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" />
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here is what I have so far which isn't working (bear with me, I do not know javascript...).

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if (screen.width > 480) {
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    document.write("
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" />
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" />
    ");
    </div>
} else {
    document.write("<img src="images/slide1.jpg" />");
}
</script>
```

The slider is really messing up how the site looks when viewing from a mobile browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lot of errors at that `JavaScript` code:

1. You can't write html code between `JavaScript` code, in the `JavaScript` html tag.
2. You must use `"` for open and close strings if it's something in there that need 's 
   double quotes to, you may change that for a simple quote.
3. Last you need to idintificate the element you want to put that images else will be added at the final of the document.

Take a look at that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6jPh/1/) for better understand.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Really appreciate the time you took to teach me

Answer (score 1):

your code is actually fine , minus the changes that Xdevelop mentioned.
Apart from this why don't you use Window.innerWidth instead while checking for width?
Also, you should actually wait for the entire page to load and then check for screen size.

Like this

```
    window.onload = function(){
    if (window.innerWidth > 480) {
    document.write("
    <div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>
    <img src='images/slide1.jpg' />
    <img src='images/slide2.jpg' />
    <img src='images/slide3.jpg' />
     </div>
     </div>
     ");

} else {
document.write("<img src='images/slide1.jpg' />");
}
```

}

Hope this works for you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you are using jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if ($( window ).width() > 480) {

    document.write("
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" />
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" />
    </div>
    ");

} else {
    document.write("<img src="images/slide1.jpg" />");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work. I tried replacing the images with just "Hello world", but still nothing showed up.